# Are Pasch's axiom and plane separation postulate equivalent?

Tags: geometry, logic, noneuclidean-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

What is the relationship between Pasch's axiom, plane separation postulate, and betweeness?

Specifically, are any of the following derivable from each other:

1. Pasch's axiom
2. In the plane, a line partitions its complement into two sets, $P$ and $Q$, such that any segment with points in both $P$ and $Q$ must intersect the line
3. Similar to #2, but adding *and any segment in with both endpoints in $P$ does not intersect the line*
4. Similar to #2 or #3, but using *circle* or *triangle* instead of *line*.

Wikipedia claims an [equivalence between Pasch's Axiom and Plane Separation Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom#Equivalences) but does not prove it or even provide a definition of the Plane Separation Axiom they claim is equivalent.

Similarly, it's been argued that [betweeness is undefined without Pasch's axiom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901133/euclids-elements-missing-axiom-of-m-pasch-examples). I have trouble accepting this for several reasons:

1. Betweeness seems to me to come directly from Euclid's Common Notions, which implicitly assume a. a total ordering over segments of the same line and b. a notion of part-whole decomposition of a segment.  It seems clear that these can be used to define betweenesss.
2. Hilbert's axioms define betweeness without using Pasch's axiom (which is incorporated separately); likewise for Tarski
3. The concept of betweeness (or its violation) does not seem to depend on plane separation, and vice versa.  I can imagine models which violate one of them but not both.

## Update: Which Axioms?

My preferred system of axioms is that of Tarski, as eventually simplified, e.g. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms).  I'm particularly interested in what happens if the Axiom of Continuity is replaced with an axiom only asserting the points needed for an Euclidean Field (but not full completeness).

Comment: To answer your question one should know what are other axioms and undefined notions that you accepted. What can be used to prove the derivability of one properties from the others?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Edited accordingly.

Comment: The implication (1) => (2,3) is proved in the book of Schwabhauser, Szmielew and Tarski and the proof is rather long. (3)=>(2) => (1) is simple. (4) for triangle seems to be equivalent to (1)--(3) (even without axioms of continuity or parallel in Tarski system). But the case of circle is special and is not true without the continuty axiom. It requires the so-called Circle-Line Continuity.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Can you confirm that the circle is not true in a Euclidean Field without the Continuity Axiom? I am very surprised by that! Can you construct an example?

Comment: The fact that the field of scalars in Tarski geometry (without the continuity axiom) is an Eucliden file is equivalent to the Circle-Line Axiom, which is equivalent to the Circle-Circle Axiom. Without those weaker continuity axioms, the field of scalars is only Pithagorean (in the sense that for every scalars $x,y$ there exists $z$ such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$).

Comment: Michael Beeson has a lot of papers explaining all those continuity Tarski-Hilbert nuances: https://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/pubs.php

Comment: Going from (1) to (2) is easy using [Hilbert's version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_axioms) of Pasch's axiom, but for some reason Tarski's version (as on Wikipedia) is different, and I'm not sure how to go between the two.